# Create HTML DOM in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML page, where I have got the page and the title. Now I stored the page content and page title in the jQuery variable:

```
$content = jQuery('div p').find ('content').text();
$title = jQuery('div').find ('title').text();
```

Now I want to create an HTML DOM like:

```
<div class="enter-content">
  <h4>$title</h4>
  <p>$content</p>
</div>
```

Then I want to store this HTML DOM in a variable.

Comment: `var domobj = $('<div class="enter-content"><h4>'+$title+'</h4><p>'+$content+'</p></div>');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var yourDOM=$('<div class="enter-content"><h4>'+$title+'</h4><p>'+$content+'</p></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, just an alternative and can be easier to manage.

```
var title = jQuery('div').find ('title').text();
var content = jQuery('div p').find ('content').text();

var HTML = new String("");
HTML += '<div class="enter-content">';
HTML += '<h4>##Title##</h4>';
HTML += '<p>##Content##</h4>';
HTML += '</div>';
HTML = HTML.replace(/##Title##/g, title);
HTML = HTML.replace(/##Content##/g, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a HTML string by concatenation is not a good idea if you expect `$title` and `$content` to contain special characters (e.g. `<`). A safe solution would look like this:

```
var div = $("<div class='enter-content'/>").append($("<h4/>").text($title)).append($("<p/>").text($content));
```